# How to re-initialize a class object in Python?

Tags: python

I have the following Python class

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, my_list = []):
        self.my_list = my_list
    
    def addItem(self, item):
        self.my_list.append(item)
```

And I'm trying to create several objects from that class. However, `my_list` continues to be shared between the different instances.

For example, with the following two initializations

```
first_instance = MyClass()
first_instance.addItem("One")
first_instance.addItem("Two")

print(first_instance.my_list)

second_instance = MyClass()
print(second_instance.my_list)
```

I get the following output

```
['One', 'Two']
['One', 'Two']
```

I would have expected the `second_instance.my_list` to produce an empty list.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change to

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, my_list = None):
        self.my_list = my_list if my_list is not None else []
```

Comment: It works, thanks! But what's wrong with my implementation?

Comment: @TarekOraby. The default values are assigned to the method when the method is created. Therefore all calls will share the same object.

Comment: @TarekOraby. Here's another thread about this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/1412534